# if date time difference is over cetain amount

Tags: php

```
$now = new DateTime();
$future_date = new DateTime($date);

$interval = $future_date->diff($now);

echo $interval->format("%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds");
```

Basically I want to use the difference between the two dates now and whatever the person has booked. I need to use an if statement to check if the difference is between 24 hours / 1 day.

how do i use datetime in if statements?
like

If ($interval > 24 hours) {
allow } my problem is how do i write 24 hours in php? sounds really dumb I know.

Answer (score 1):

```
$now_ts = $now->getTime();
$future_date_ts = $future_date->getTime();
if ($future_date_ts - $now > 60 * 60 * 24) {
    // more than 24 hours before $future_date
}
```

If you also want the diff the other way add:

```
$now - $future_date_ts > 60 * 60 * 24 // more than 24 hours after $future_date
```

This gives you a 48 hour range around `$future_date`.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use the UNIX timestamp ( the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

time(); will return the current Unix timestamp and you can convert your future_date to a timestamp using strtotime();

So you can calculate the difference in seconds using:

```
$diff_secs = strtotime($future_date) - time();
```

And knowing 1 day is 24 hours which is 24*60 minutes which is 24*60*60 seconds,

```
$diff_days = (strtotime($future_date) - time())/(24*60*60);
```

Or you could use the difference in hours as your comparison :

```
$diff_hours = (strtotime($future_date) - time())/(60*60);
if($diff_hours > 24) {
    //do something if its more than 24 hours away
 }
```

Comment: `DateTime->getTime()` will return negative values for dates before the epoch. On 64-bit systems you have all the range you need.